# Can I make an element the width of its contents via pure CSS?

Tags: css

I need to make an element be the full width of it's contents.

I was doing something like this with `whitespace:no-wrap` and `display: inline-block;`, but it was a scroll effect. Now I need to have the element be the actual width of it's contents; not scroll to view them (because I need a wrapper with a single full width content item for a certain JS solution with scrolling effects).

My setup is like this (where `#content` should be full width):

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
#content {
  white-space: nowrap;
  
  /* this is a false solution, since the contents must be variable */
  width: 1000px;
  /* this is a false solution, since the contents must be variable */
  
  background-color: blue;
}
.inner_item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">
    <!-- this should be as wide as all of its contents combined -->
    <div class="inner_item"></div>
    <div class="inner_item"></div>
    <div class="inner_item"></div>
    <div class="inner_item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**(How) Can I make an element the width of its contents via pure CSS?**

Clarification:

The #content element, which wraps sub-content items, should actually overflow past the edge of it's parent container, not scroll its inner content. So if there are 5x 1000px wide items inside of #content, and I do `$('#content').width()` I should get `5000`. That's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: How about width: 100%; ?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ I tried that but I think it makes the element 100% of the page width.

Comment: So, if the content-width should exceed the width of the browser, what should happen? Should the excess content wrap or be hidden?

Comment: in your example, which element do you want to be full width?

Comment: @DavidThomas it sould be hidden (in the Snippet, you'll see that `#content` has a wrapper which scrolls overflow.

Comment: You need to edit your question and be more specific: do both the `#wrapper` **and** the `#content` elements need to have the exact same width as your `.inner_item` divs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the specs in your question are not very clear to me, but it looks like this is what you could be looking for.

```
#wrapper, #wrapper * {
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    width:500px;
}
#content {
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.inner_item {
    display:inline-block;
    width:250px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
}
.inner_item:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}
```

### Fiddle:

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/0L0kwc3r/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

apply the following styles to element `#content`

```
#content{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

And you can also follow @Rooster's advice and remove `overflow-x` from `#wrapper`

Check [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jrwrxt87/2/)

Comment: and take the overflow-x rule off wrapper

Comment: The default value for width is "auto" so you probably dont need it.

Comment: I accepted this for a moment, but realized it scrolls the content. What I'm asking for is a content box that expands to fit all of it's children (the #content element, which wraps sub-content items, should actually overflow). So if there are 5x 1000px wide items inside of #content, and I do `$('#content').width()` I should get `5000`.